# How to retrieve currentUser data with Vue.js, AWS Amplify, and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, firebase, express, vue.js, aws-amplify

I am attempting to build a Vue.js App that synthesizes properties of AWS, MongoDB, and Express. I built an authentication page for the app using `aws-amplify` and `aws-amplify-vue`. After logging into the app, metadata containing the username for the logged in AWS user is passed into data object property `this.name` like so:

```
  async beforeCreate() {
    let name = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    this.name = name.username
  }
```

`this.name` is then added to MongoDB via Axios:

```
    async addName() {
        let uri = 'http://localhost:4000/messages/add';
        await this.axios.post(uri, {
          name: this.name,
        })
        this.getMessage()
      }
```

I also have a `getName()` method that I am using to retrieve that data from MongoDB:

```
    async getData () {
      let uri = 'http://localhost:4000/messages';
      this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
        this.userData = response.data;
      });
    },
```

This method, however, returns data for ALL users. I want to reconfigure this method to ONLY return data for `.currentAuthenticatedUser()`. In my previous experience with Firebase, I would set up my `.getData()` method with something like:

```
let ref = db.collection('users')
let snapshot = await ref.where('user_id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()
```

...in order to return currentUser information on the condition that 'user_id' in the collection matches the currently logged-in Firebase user.

To achieve this with MongoDB, I attempted to configure the above method like so:

```
    async getData () {
      let uri = 'http://localhost:4000/messages';
      let snapshot = await uri.where('name', '==', this.name);
      this.axios.get(snapshot).then(response => {
        this.userData = response.data;
      });
    },
```

My thought here was to try and return current user data by comparing 'name' in the MongoDB collection with the logged-in user stored in `this.name`...but I understand that this might not work because the `.where()` method is probably unique to Firebase. Any recommendations on how to configure this `.getData()` to return ONLY data associated with the currentAuthenticatedUser? Thanks!

EXPRESS ROUTES:

```
const express = require('express');
const postRoutes = express.Router();

// Require Post model in our routes module
let Post = require('./post.model');

// Defined store route
postRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
  let post = new Post(req.body);
  post.save()
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({'business': 'business in added successfully'});
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});

// Defined get data(index or listing) route
postRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = postRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to apply a `where` clause to a uri AFAIK. What you should do is adding a `where` clause to the actual query you are making in your backend and, to do that, send the `username` you want to filter the query with through a query parameter like this: `/messages?name=JohnDoe`.

So basically if you are using a Node/Express backend, as you suggested, and using Mongoose as the ODM for MongoDB your request would probably be looking something like this:

```js
const Users = require('../models/users.model');

Users.find({}, function (e, users) {
    if (e) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            'error': e
        })
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        'data': users
    });
})
```

What you should do is getting the `username` query parameter through `req.query` and add it to the options in the first parameter of the `find` function.

```js
const Users = require('../models/users.model');

let params = {},
    name = req.query.name;

if (name) {
    params.name = name
}

Users.find(params, function (e, users) {
    if (e) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            'error': e
        })
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        'data': users.slice
    });
})
```

That way if you point to `/messages?name=John` you will get the users with "John" as their name.

**Edit**:

If your backend is configured in the following way

```js
postRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
});
```

what you should do is get the query parameters from inside the get method

```js
postRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    let params = {},
        name = req.query.name

    if (name) {
       params.name = name
    }

    Post.find(params, function(err, posts){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Please see the Express Routes above that I added to my question. I am indeed using Mongoose, but my routes are set up a little different than the ones you posted. How can I still use ```req.query``` in an Express route setup like the one I am using?

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing, I'll add it now to my answer.

Comment: Excellent. I implemented that. As far as prompting the route to return username data, I attempted to configure the query paramater in ```getData()``` to look like this: ```http://localhost:4000/messages?username=${this.name}``` by passing in the targeted username into the URL, but this still did not work. Based on your answer regarding the query parameter, how can I configure the query parameter in the URL to send a request based on the authenticated user?

Comment: Perhaps because the name of your field in the db is `name` and not `username`. Try making it `/messages?name=${this.name}` and in the backend replace `username` with `name`. I just used `username` because it was descriptive and I didn't know what was the name of your field.

Comment: The trick was to pass in the authenticated name into the query parameter, and then configure the Express route to query that name, then respond with data based on that queried name

Comment: getting the query parameters INSIDE the method like you said was the big game changer.